# my server is no conncting.its shown error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

First I install,

```
npx create-react-app amazon-clone
```

then I want to start. so I type

```
npm start
```

but I get an error.
my JSON file adds below.

```
{
  "name": "amazon-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**why I am getting the error??**
I see many stackoverflow answer but didn't get the point

Comment: try npm run start

Comment: what error did you got?

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\meetv\Desktop\amzon project\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\meetv\Desktop\amzon project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\meetv\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-09T04_37_10_573Z-debug.log

Comment: try deleting package.lock.json and then do npm i again. This should work!

Comment: npm install would work after deleting package-lock.json

Comment: hello @Mr Khan..thanks for your time. but package-lock.json. lekin fir bhi nahi huva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to change the directory. Follow the steps below.

```
npx create-react-app amazon-clone
cd amazon-clone
npm start
```